# using public shared on a master page can't access it from a class

Tags: asp.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm using asp.net and vb.net as the code behind.  In the masterpage of an existing website I had this

```
namespace WebAdminV2
{
public partial class WebAdmin : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public static SitePlumbing.CurrentSession oCurrentSession;
```

WebAdmin is the name of the masterpage.

In another class i was using this shared current session with this code

```
  CurrentSession O = WebAdminV2.WebAdmin.oCurrentSession;
```

That worked.  Now i'm trying to convert it to vb.net and having the problem where it does not see the WebAdminV2.WebAdmin.oCurrentSesion.  The master page looks like this

```
Namespace WebAdminV2
Partial Class WebAdmin
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Public Shared oCurrentSession As SitePlumbing.CurrentSession
```

and the class trying to use oCurrentSession

```
Dim O As CurrentSession = WebAdminV2.WebAdmin.oCurrentSession
```

It tells me that WebAdminV2 is not declared.  If i comment out the line above the site does compile without errors.  The class that I'm trying to use that will reference the oCurrentSesion on the master page is not another page.

Anyway, I'd like to understand what i've done wrong.
Thanks
Shannon

Comment: Is `oCurrentSession` supposed to be user specific?

Comment: yes.. it will be only for that user

Comment: Then it shouldn't be static/shared. Those variables are shared across the entire process. You should use some other form of persistence, such as Session or cookies etc.

Comment: that makes sense. so busy trying to convert the code didn't bother to think about it.  Appreciate your help